# Which code is cleaner with better design?

Tags: c, loops, do-while, cs50

Exhibit A

So this code has the printf function and the integer input is stored afterwords. Is this clean code?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int main(void)
{
    int input;
    do
    {
        printf("Enter a positive number: \n");
        input = get_int();
    }
    while (input <= 0);
}
```

Exhibit B

I prefer this one since there's less lines, but are the end results the same in comparison between the two?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int main(void)
{
    int input;
    do
    {
        input = get_int("Please enter a positive integer: \n");
    }
    while (input <= 0);
}
```

Comment: It really is up to you. If your question is "Do I take a prompt for my `get_int` function?" or do I just prompt before calling -- it's 6 to one, 1/2 dozen to another.

Comment: which example :/

Comment: The [reference](https://reference.cs50.net/cs50/get_int) shows `get_int` as taking at least one parameter.

Answer (score 1):

`get_int()` takes a format string as its first argument and optional arguments that must be consistent with the format. The first code has undefined behavior because you do not pass the correct arguments to `get_int()`.

It is advisable to provide more information to the user. It is also better style to return 0 from `main()`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int main(void) {
    int input;
    while ((input = get_int("Please enter a positive integer: ")) <= 0) {
        printf("The number entered %d is not strictly positive\n", input);
    }
    return 0;
}
```